# How to smartly optimize ads on website

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, optimization

I've a content website that presents ads.

Now, my team want to optimize it for a better experience for the users. (we really believe our ads are good for our users.)

We are sure that every website deals with this issue and there must be some known ways and methods to deal with it, that smart people thought of before.

so what i'm looking is a tested, working method to optimize ads.

for example:

- if i was asking about optimizing my website in Google, I would expect
  you to answer me: learn SEO
- if i was asking about optimizing the use of my website: usability testing.
- navigation: information architecture

what is the field that deals with optimizing ads?

Comment: What do you mean by 'optimizing'? Is it money? Clicks? Position?

Comment: Are your users logged in? Can you retrieve info about them from the DB?

Comment: @JVerstry optimizing is more clicks

Comment: @dm-guy they are not logged in.

Answer (score 3):

Probably [AB testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing)

AB test your pages by showing different ads to different groups of users, record and track the best variations to optimize your CTAs

Comment: AB testing is a general method to check between 2 things, and how they perform. although it suits my case, im looking for something more specific for the case of ads.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is [google-adsense](/questions/tagged/google-adsense) tagged, so the first what you will probably want to try are "AdSense Experiments". https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/4599562?hl=en

> Here are some examples of the types of experiments that you can run:
>
> - Compare the performance of text-only ad units to ad units that have
>     both text and display enabled
> - Analyze the effect of changing the color
>     of ad text on ad performance
> - Determine the impact on your revenue of
>     using ad serving, sensitive and/or general category blocks

You will probably notice you can't test different *fixed* ad sizes with AdSense Experiments feature. I'm not 101% sure, and I think that is because AdSense is already optimizing them with "Similar-sized display ads". https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3234887?hl=en

But you *can* see which sizes are better performing on that slot, in your perfomance reports: on "Ad units" page click on ad unit name, and then switch "Days" dimension to "Creative sizes". https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2546700?hl=en

Also, there is "A/B testing" listed as acceptable on "Modification of the AdSense ad code" page:
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en

And you can connect AdSense account with Analytics:
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/98155?hl=en

(It is completely non-related to your question, but *just* because we are talking about experiments with AdSense ads, it may be worth to mention and to keep in mind: if you create `width: X; height: Y;` ad unit, but you need `M*N` for experiment, then you **can't** just manually change ad code to `width: M; height: N;` and you will need to create new `M*N` ad unit.)